# Use HTML editor in WordPress theme options

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have a `<textarea>` in my wp theme settings. How can I convert this to use the wordpress HTML editor instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wp_editor()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor).

Example:

```
$editor_settings =  array (
    'textarea_rows' => 8
,   'media_buttons' => FALSE
,   'teeny'         => TRUE
,   'tinymce'       => FALSE
    // a very minimal setup
,   'quicktags'     => array ( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link' )
);
wp_editor( $content, $key, $editor_settings );
```

For a better example see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/43742/73) and the [tag wp-editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp-editor) on [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This worked perfectly. But is there a way to customize the buttons in `wp_editor()`?

Comment: Yes, look at the example: The `'buttons'` key accepts a comma separated list of button names.