# how to use wp editor

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am newbie to wordpress theme development...

i know to create theme options in wordpress themes but now i want to use WYSIWYG Editor of wordpress, the wp_editor(), i have read some tuts on this but i can't make it...

here is my code:

```
    add_settings_field('tinytxt', 'WYSIWYG: ', array($this, 'tinytxt'), 'oditer_theme_options', 'jd_theme_options_main_section');



public function tinytxt() {

     wp_editor("{$this->options['tinytxt']}", 'tinytxtboom');
}
```

And how to retrieve the saved content from the database, i know to use get_option()...

thanks in advance...

Comment: Try doing just `wp_editor($this->options['tinytxt'], 'tinytxtboom');`. If that doesn't work, `var_dump` `$this->options`, and see what's in it.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049856/use-html-editor-in-wordpress-theme-options

Comment: the first doesn't worked, and the dumping the var just printed the whole serialized data in which 'tinytxt' does not exist...

Comment: can you please provide me complete guide or video to wp editor??

Comment: okay, now tinytxt is in $options, here is the result of dumping:

 ["tinytxt"]=> string(0) ""

Comment: You're using `wp_editor` right, you just aren't saving and/or loading the input. You probably need to set [`textarea_name`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor).

Comment: can you please guide me?
thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara here is ma whole code: http://pastebin.com/E9MQkB8T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your WordPress editor a name for the input, so that it can save the value.

```
wp_editor( $this->options['tinytxt'], 'tinytxtboom', array(
    'textarea_name' => 'jd_theme_options[tinytxt]'
) );
```

This will give the hidden textarea `wp_editor` uses a `name` for the form submission. `jd_theme_options` matches the second argument to `register_setting`, and `tinytxt` is the option key you want to save the value under.

I think that's all you need. Comment if you have trouble. I'll be back tomorrow to check.

You could also try getting it to work with just a simple textarea, then try to get the wp_editor working.